# React - caching data so app will work offline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am looking to create an App (a game) which will get its data from an API but once it has that data will work offline if necessary. I therefore want to:

1. Keep a copy of the data in localStorage
2. Be able to operate offline with the stored data it has if no network connectivity by caching the results of API calls

Unfortunately its been some time since I last did something similar and I can code it manually, but is there a more modern way of doing this? I wish to have permanent access to about 1000 objects which get their data from an API call `https://myapi/{name}`. If I have a local copy of the object, I only need to try and update it if more than 24 hours has elapsed, but even if that fails due to no connectivity I can use the existing data if I have it.

So my thoughts are that I can subscribe to a **Redux** store to save to local storage, but how do I manage the API calls and updating of the objects? I am thinking of using something like `react-query` or `RTK Query` but don't know how to go about this. I can already query the API using `RTK Query` but am uncertain how to use it to get my specialised requirements addressed.

Comment: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/persistence-and-rehydration#redux-persist

Comment: Well that simplifies the local storage side - thanks